# Can't make CORS work, got headers, got 200 response

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cors

Im trying to implement an API based on PHP and Slim, but keep getting CORS error “No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource” error .  But clearly I have it set.

I have searched all over the internet to enable CORS in my api.

Url for testing: http://www.ricardochen.com/index2.php

I have even stripped everything down to just this (php):

```
<?php
$data = "test";
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

.htaccess

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"

RewriteEngine On
# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

My header according to chrome inspector

GENERAL:

```
Request URL:http://ricardochen.com/index2.php
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:198.46.81.208:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Response Headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:1000
Connection:Upgrade, Keep-Alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Fri, 19 Jan 2018 23:08:32 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=3, max=100
Server:Apache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Upgrade:h2,h2c
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.45
```

Request Headers

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:_ga=GA1.2.637285574.1502508699
Host:ricardochen.com
Pragma:no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
```

I have tried setting the header in php, in .htaccess, in both, tried in 2 different shared hostings, tried on my localhost and same behaviour.

Please help

Comment: Maybe it worth to try:
`<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/47zc8326/ appears to work just fine.

Comment: Are you sure you send back `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to all requests and for preflight `OPTION` request as well?

Comment: @Ivar sorry I had an incorrect file for testing, I just reverted it, can you try again please.

Comment: Still not getting an CORS error when I try it.

Comment: @DmytroY.  At this point I'm not sure about preflight, I can't get a simple GET to pass. I'm also using this site to verify: test-cors.org

Comment: @RicardoChenHe It sends `OPTIONS` request automatically to find out if `GET` is allowed on the resource. The server should set headers on that too.

Comment: @Ivar Oh... you have in the url httpS , I get error when I use regular http, interesting. But in my "real" hosting, I belive I do not have httpS

Comment: @RicardoChenHe I've sent GET request and got correct response to both OPTIONS and GET.

Comment: @DmytroY. , I think this is those WTF moments, where things doesnt appear to work until you ask for help.  Now it seems to work, at leat with the .htaccess method.

Answer (score 0):

When cross origin request is performed, a browser sends `OPTIONS` request beforehand to find out what is allowed and expects to get headers in response like following:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Method: OPTIONS, GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: OPTIONS, GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
```

After a browser sees these headers, it knows it is allowed to make `GET` request. Ensure your reply to `OPTIONS` correctly.

Comment: As my understanding preflight do not affect GET,  I might be worng

Answer (score -1):

At the end did not know what happened, probably my testing methods was the issue.

It is working.

Thanks.

Comment: for me , sometimes it's passing with `GET 200` and sometimes no response `OPTIONS 200` , have you figured out yet the actual reason ?